What happens on a CAN bus when impedance is too low?
Assuming impedance is matched with proper end resistors:
What is the actual problem on a CAN bus with impedance considerably lower than 120 ohm? For example, transmission line and terminations both at 85 ohms.
Is it that the transceivers will not be able to drive the CAN_HIGH and CAN_LOW lines to the correct voltage levels?

So just to be sure, you are asking what happens if the bus transmission line is e.g. 85 ohms and terminated with matching 85 ohm terminations at both ends of the cable? Or is only the transmission line e.g. 85 ohms but with original 120 ohm terminations?

Correct, transmission line and terminations both at 85 ohms.

The CAN transceiver is designed and guaranteed to drive a certain load.
For example, the MCP2551 will drive a load of 45 ohms on the CAN bus. Each device on CAN bus adds a bit of load to the bus.
Therefore the MCP2551 is guaranteed to drive up to 112 CAN nodes if the bus is terminated to standard 120 ohms at both ends and each node adds 20 kohms to the bus.
So if you for example use 85 ohm cable for which you need 85 ohm terminations on each end of the cable, that's already a load of 42.5 ohms so technically the MCP2551 is not guaranteed to drive any nodes at all.
With 100 ohm trasmission line and terminations, you get around 44 nodes.
So yes, using lower impedances, there is a limit where the driver is unable to drive the bus voltage to the specified voltages.

The actual input threshold voltage is much lower than driven, to allow for loss along the bus.
An overloaded bus does three things:

Less signal level at the transmitter itself; yes, that's one part of it.
A transmitter might not be rated to drive less than 60 ohms, continuously, as well: thermal limits, excess supply consumption, etc. apply.

More voltage drop along a bus of given resistance (and AC loss).  This tends to reduce range.  This can be mitigated with proper transmission line design (lower Zo, but lower loss) -- but see, it will be more expensive than the intended solution, too.

Potential for reflection.  You account for this in the condition (proper termination), but this might not happen in practice -- say, attaching a standard device with an internal (fixed or switched) 120Ω terminator.  It's not going to terminate a 90Ω bus very well, etc.  Conversely, if the bus is still 120Ω Zo, but erroneously-low terminators were used, reflection results.


Again--excepted as given, but worth highlighting, as real situations vary, and one may get an incorrect impression from reading this, that random values are okay (if the transmitter's okay with it and reduced maximum range isn't relevant) but also missing the complete scope of that exception (what it means to properly match bus and terminators).  Lord knows I misread things all the time -- casual readers here will as well, and I just want to emphasize this point.

The question is not about overloading the bus. It's about using a cable with an impedance other than 120 ohms for practical reasons.

Overloaded relative to specification, that is.
